# Error 1 File 'Windows.props' not found. Visual Studio 2013 Premium

Tags: windows, windows-8, emulator, windows-phone, visual-studio-2013

I'm getting the error `Error 1 File 'Windows.props' not found.` every time I try to build a JS Store app (Windows, Windows Phone or Universal).

I've been getting this error ever since i installed the 'Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator', I have tried restoring my PC to a previous state (a day before the installation), repairing multiple times, removing the Emulator, re-installing Visual Studio and I have also tried building on a different user account.

According to a few sources on the internet the windows.props file should be located in the following directory.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone
>   Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\

Its not located in that directory.  But I did locate the `Windows.props` file in the following directory.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone
>   Kits\8.1\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\

There is a [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442152/file-windows-props-not-found) question similar to this but I couldn't find an answer that helped me.

Here is the information contained in my registry

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Install Path` was set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\`

and

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\Install Path` was set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\`

The complete error is

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Tar‌​gets(561,9):
>   error APPX1639: File 'Windows.props' not found. See
>   go.microsoft.com/fwlink/… for more information

Comment: @Ramhound no the error only provides a <a hre="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12395&pver=1.0&plcid=0x409&ar=MSDN&sar=PlatformMultiTargeting&o1=Windows&o2=8.1">link</a>. I tried copying it from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\` but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Be sure you have `VS2013 Update 2` installed

Comment: You have two options. Place the file indicated by the current registry value or change the registry value to the current location of the file.  Can you please take 2-3 minutes and format the question so its not a huge block of text?

Comment: @Ramhound what do you mean by "Place the file indicated by the current registry value"?

Comment: The build script is attempting to locate the file in the following location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1` and since its actually located in `C:\Program Files (x86) Windows Phone Kits\8.1\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral` the build script fails.  Using the verbose logging would have indicated this.

Comment: @Ramhound There are 3-4 windows.props files on my PC, I think the windows.props in `C:\Program Files (x86) Windows Phone Kits\8.1\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral` is in the right place. the closest file to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1` is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Portable\v12.0\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral`

Comment: @Ramhound OK so 1. the files are different. 2. after copying the file I am still getting the same error

Comment: are you talking about the build output? there's nothing like $(TargetPlatformWinMDLocation) in that

Comment: If `TargetPlatformWinMDLocation =` is not in the build output you have not enabled verbose logging like I requested.

Comment: Hans Passant talks about it in the question you linked to, which I found, before I realized you linked to it. Everything I have ask for is contained in his answer. If you have not already restarted Visual Studio after moving files or changing registry keys you should do that.  [Verbose logging](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verbose)

Comment: `Ctrl+A` to select everything then use `Ctrl+C` to copy what is selected then use `Ctrl+V` into notepad then `Ctrl+F` to find the text I am asking about.

Comment: With the verbose build output?  It sounds like you should perform a clean install of Visual Studio 2013 and make sure you install Update 2.  `Because the macro in question is required.`

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issues for Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. Repairing VS fixed the problem. I believe this issue is caused because the updates doesn't get installed properly for unknown reasons.